# SELECT statement with BOOLEAN

Tags: mysql

I need to make a select statement that lists all the artists and whether they have more than 5 million in sales or not (yes/no). The artists need to be sorted alphabetically.

Artists table columns: artist_id, name.
Songs table columns: song_id, title, sales.
song_artist table columns (junction): song_id, artist_id

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. I used `left join` on `Songs` table in case we need to view those `artist` without sales yet.

```
select t1.name, 
    case when sum(t3.sales) >= 5000000 then 'yes' else 'no' end as million_sales
from Artists t1
inner join Song_Artist t2 on t2.artis_id = t1.artist_id
left join Songs t3 on t3.song_id = t2.song_id
group by t1.name
order by t1.name
```